# 2 column layout pushing other content down

Tags: html, css

Image of problem: http://expansion-mc.com/layout.png

[image]

As you can see from the image, I have a 2 column blog which has content that pushes other content down. How can I make it so that the content is tight together and doesn't have the gap caused by the right column. I am using Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 blog-post pull-">
    <h3 id="sample_postTitle" class="post-title">
        Highlights from around the server #2
    </h3>
    <hr class="blog-hr">
    <p id="sample_postContent" class="post-content">
        Content
    </p>
    <hr class="pull-left blog-hr" width="5%">
    <sup class="pull-left text-muted post-meta">
        posted by <i>MrDarrenGriffin</i>, 22nd November 2014
    </sup>
    <hr class="pull-left blog-hr" width="10%">
</div>
```

Comment: as this issue, you need to show your code

Comment: You are perhaps looking for this: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: cant i fix this just via css?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly this might be of help

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0; padding-left:0;
}
```

Then add no-litter to your containing row