# Unable to clear floats in responsive layout, lengthy content box pushes others down

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, css-float

Floated list items, where if one item is longer than the rest it will push other list items down across the entire UL. I've tried unsuccessful combinations of `vertical-align:top`, `float:top`, `clear:none`, and `overflow:hidden`.

This is part of a responsive content display, the code where the problem occurs can be found in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/t910gv2v/

**Q.** How can I either prevent all of the menus from being pushed down when space above is available OR specifically target the "odd one out" and push it upward?

The code structure (ul > li > div) is what I have to work with and unless responsible for the problem should be the same

Similar to this unsolved post: [2 column layout pushing other content down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460044/2-column-layout-pushing-other-content-down)

Comment: Hey, `float: top;` doesn't exsist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you are attempting to put 5 elements with a `width: 25%;`. Of course, the 5fth element will fall down! You have to use `width: 20%;` for all 5 elements to fit.

What I mean is that, by using `width: 25%;` you are figuratively "dividing the parent element in 4 parts", so of course, a 5fth 25% width element won't fit.

And remmember, `float: top;` doesn't exist: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: Yes I should have made a note, I did that to recreate my problem. On my end the width is based on media queries, the problem is with the list items, floats, or something I cannot place that occurs in the fiddle.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: This is what I'm facing, more or less what is happening in the fiddle: http://i.imgur.com/EQS4kRm.jpg

Comment: Oh I get it now... That's normal float behavior. If you want the element to stick up disregarding the height of alike elements, you should try a 3 column approach, instead of floats.